# Is there a way to convert Vis to a form i can use in research?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I have Thaumcraft 4 and I thoroughly enjoy it however I am reaching a dead end in my research as I am running out of Aspects, particular primal ones.

I have a deconstruction table however I have 3 64 block stacks of sandstone, I got no Aer or Ordo Primal Aspects and I needed both to make some more aspects for some research. I had to hunt quite a ways from my village and workshop in order to find undiscovered nodes which I could scan.

I have a bunch of gold cap greatwood wands which are all full of vis and I have plenty of nodes I can go to in order to refill, so I am wondering if there is a way to convert my collected vis to research escapades?

Comment: @Ben Vis is the stuff you collect in the wand from nodes which is then placed on an enchanting table and used in some casting recipes. what i am talking about is converting that to the primal aspects you use for research that way insted of having to hike away from my workshop to find more i can just collect vis from nearby nodes and convert the huge surplice for recherche since i am currently out of Ordo in Research but i have 2 wands full of it

Comment: which Thaumcraft are you using, 3 or 4?

Comment: @Ben *"I have Thaumcraft 4"*

Comment: I knew I read that somewhere... *slaps forehead*

Comment: Try breaking down more complex items like bows or tools, they have a higher chance for giving aspects through the deconstruction table.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantely my research efforts have returned zip on the topic of extracting aspects from wands, so I will have to go off my experience of the previous versions.

From Thaumcraft 2 (and 3), Vis was a force that was in, well, everything. It was constantly regenerating, and was independent of Aura Nodes. Wands were the main use of Vis, used in the workbench to create Thaumcraft items and to create Thaumcraft constructs (like the Infernal Furnace).

In Thaumcraft 4, Vis is taking a turn towards the "All is One, One is all" side of things, and Saying that Vis comes from the Primal Aspects of nature: Aer (air), Terra (earth), Ignis (fire), Aqua (water), Ordo (order), and Perditio (entropy). These were originally stored in the Vis Crystals in previous versions, found underground (Vis infused stone) and were "the purest form of Vis".

Therefore, it would seem the modders added this into the structure of the mod to make it more complex. However, it is little more than that; Vis *drawn* from a particular Aspect.

Comment: And in the research you use knowledge about the aspect.

Comment: One more voice to the choir here; no. What you're looking for (a direct conversion from vis stored in your wand into primal aspect points for research) doesn't exist. To get research points you either have to scan things or break things down in your deconstruction table. My personal favorite thing to put in there is rotten flesh. It's easy to get (make a mob grinder) and you get a LOT of every type of primal aspect because the aspects that it contains are about as complex as anything. Basically, the more steps between the item and its primal the more likely it will yield a research point.

Comment: As an addendum; vis stored in your wand *could* be used to kill zombies, which will give you rotten flesh (and brains, sometimes!) which will give you research points! Less direct than you're looking for and not really an answer to your question, but hey - it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use many Essentia Crystallizers to turn essentia into Crystallized Essence. Put those into Deconstruction Table. Deconstruction Table has a chance to turn them into their respective research points.